# JS Discord Rankbot

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am working on a system which Auto Ranks you in our discord server when visited. The page would be private and visited by a different source code (in lua).

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    let Member = req.param("Discord");

    async function abc() {
        let guild = await Client.guilds.cache.get("893848693248241744");
        let member = await guild.members.cache.get(Member);
        var role = await guild.roles.cache.get("893848693248241747");

        console.log(member.ToString())
        member.roles.add(role).catch(console.error);
    }
    abc()
        
    res.json({"status": "true", "userid": req.param("Discord")})
});
```

The variable "member" gets returned nil. What do I do?
Discord.js v12

Comment: 1) What does `Member` return? 2) `.get()` does not return a promise, no need to `await`. 3) It's possible that the member of the given id (assuming you're passing in a valid snowflake) is uncached, try using `fetch()` *then* you would need to use `await`

Comment: Nevermind I got it working!

Answer (score 2):

I needed to use `.fetch` instead of `.get` to fetch the uncached data

```js
let guild = await Client.guilds.fetch("893848693248241744");
let member = await guild.members.fetch(Member);
var role = await guild.roles.fetch("893848693248241747");

member.roles.add(role).catch(console.error);
```